# Godaddy Forwarding to Heroku gives SSL issue

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, dns, forwarding

I have a domain in GoDaddy and a Node JS app on Heroku. I followed the instruction on how to forward the domain to heroku, using the heroku DNS target as a Cname record for www : [Godaddy records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pWK3.png). My domain is zelakir.com. Whenever someone's typing https://www.zelakir.com everything works fine. But if you write https://zelakir.com it gives a privacy error saying the web is insecure, and if you check what is the ssl certificate, it says its issued for shortner.secureserver.net.[Certification Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ACGW.png) [Godaddy records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pWK3.png) [heroku settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7HDh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an A record for @.  @ represents your base domain, in this case `zelakir.com`.

Here is some heroku reference for custom apex domains, I think you might have to use a different DNS provider instead of GoDaddy:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain

Comment: Thats what i thought, just wanted to give Godaddy one more chance. Thanks!